# VLC - Video Streaming Synchronization

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, multicast

Using VLC 2.2.4 Weatherwax.

I'm streaming a video using UDP as multicast. Stream is displayed by 2 different clients using VLC.

I'm trying to synchronize the display on these 2 clients.

I've seen there's the "netsync" option, however I can't get it work.

Tried, --control netsync --netsync-master on server
and --control netsync --netsync-master-ip  on clients etc.

Monitoring network activity with wireshark, It's as if nothing happens, no error message even when verbose logging is on.

So, does this "netsync" module even work, or even exist in latest versions? If so, how can I make it work?

If "netsync" or anything else does not work, can I still synchronize these clients with reducing network-caching like, --network-caching=60 --sout-keep?